# How to convert MAC address to IP in Android Java?

Tags: android

I am trying to connect through socket. And it seems the address to connect must be IP but I have MAC one. How to convert MAC address to IP in Android Java?

Comment: provide more details

Answer (score 0):

MAC is derived from hardware pieces, it's unique to the machine. IP is assigned from whatever network you are accessing. These two things do not influence each other and therefore cannot be converted. You might want to try another way of finding your IP address. Maybe search the internet.

Comment: ok. I use wi fi direct. And I get MAC address of the peer in onPeersAvailable. How then can I connect to peer?